# xslt unable to assign value to a node

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt to create an xml
here code snippet for the same

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/PAYMENTS/PAYMENT">
   <xsl:if test="./PAYMENT_TYPE = 'CEDING'">
     <xsl:if test="./FIRST_NAME[ . != '']">
        <xsl:variable name="myId" select="concat('Payment', position())"/>
            <Relation ObjectID="string(concat('Payment', position()))">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Payment',position())"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </Relation>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Also I tried doing the same code as

```
<xsl:for-each select="/PAYMENTS/PAYMENT">
   <xsl:if test="./PAYMENT_TYPE = 'CEDING'">
     <xsl:if test="./FIRST_NAME[ . != '']">
        <xsl:variable name="myId" select="concat('Payment', position())"/>
            <Relation ObjectID="$myId">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Payment',position())"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </Relation>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
```

in both the cases I m getting the resulting xml node as

```
 <Relation OriginatingObjectID="string(concat('Payment', position()))" id="Payment1">
</Relation>

 <Relation OriginatingObjectID="$myId" id="Payment1">
</Relation>
```

That is its unable to cast the value for Relation Node's ObjectID.

Can any one let me know where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<Relation ObjectID="$myId">
```

with

```
<Relation ObjectID="{$myId}">
```